# np.uint32 != np.uintc on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, types

On my Windows machine:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.dtype(np.uint32).itemsize 
4
>>> np.dtype(np.uintc).itemsize  
4
>>> np.uint32 == np.uintc        
False
```

But on my Mac:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.dtype(np.uint32).itemsize
4
>>> np.dtype(np.uintc).itemsize
4
>>> np.uint32 == np.uintc
True
```

Why `np.uint32 != np.uintc` on Windows despite the same itemsize?

Comment: Not only that, but also `np.uintc is np.uint32` on my *nix machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy users typically think of a 4-level integer dtype hierarchy, that being int8, int16, int32, int64, and the unsigned variants, but internally, NumPy actually has a *5*-level hierarchy.

This 5-level hierarchy corresponds to signed and unsigned C char, short, int, long and long long. Depending on your platform, `long` will typically be the same size as either `int` or `long long`, leading to "evil twin" dtypes for either int32 or int64.

`numpy.uintc` is the dtype corresponding to C `unsigned int`, and on Mac, that's the only 32-bit unsigned integer type, so `numpy.uint32` is an alias of `numpy.uintc`. However, on Windows, `unsigned long` is also a 32-bit unsigned integer type, so `numpy.uint32` could be either `numpy.uintc` or [`numpy.uint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.uint), the dtype corresponding to C `unsigned long`. It ends up being `numpy.uint` instead of `numpy.uintc`.